# how do translate the Dynamic header of ag-grid in angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

i am just trying like this , and i do not know how it works in en.json or otherlanguage.json file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef, GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss']
})
export class DemoComponent {
  private gridApi: GridApi = null;

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { headerName: "Code", field: 'code', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) },
    { headerName: 'Version', field: 'version', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) },
    { headerName: 'IsEnabled', field: 'isEnabled', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) }
  ];

  public rowData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    })
  }

  public onGridReady(parameters: any): void {
    this.gridApi = parameters.api;
  }

  public localizeHeader(parameters: ICellRendererParams): string {
    let headerIdentifier = parameters.colDef.field;
    return this.translateService.instant(headerIdentifier);
  }
}
```

can anyone , please share  me how  en.json or es.json file should be

Answer (score 0):

Fast workaround

in .ts

```
public tableColumnsEn
public tableColumnsEs
```

in .html

```
<ag-grid-angular [columnDefs]="tableColumnsEn"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Then in language change observable

```
this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((lang) => {
  
  if (lang == 'en') ? this.tableColumns = [...tableColumnsEn] : [...tableColumnsEs]
})
```

More generic approach will be something like this:
.ts

```
 this.translateService.getStreamOnTranslationChange
.subscribe((stream) => {
      tableColumns.forEach((t) => {
       stream.forEach((key) => {
        if (t.headerName == key) t.headerName = key
      })
    })
  })
```